# How to find several files by iterating through a variable in bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, find

I want to find the files Stress_x_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt, Stress_y_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt and Stress_z_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt and delete them if they exist.

I tried creating an array of strings to iterate over them. But the compiler is telling me:

```
i: command not found
```

Part of the code is here:

```
components=('x' 'y' 'z')
for i in "${components[@]}"
    do
        if [ -f "Stress_$(i)_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt" ]; then rm    "Stress_$i_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt"; fi
    touch "Stress_$(i)_vs_Ecutoff_convergence.txt"
    done
```

I need the variable i for doing other stuff, so I would appreciate if you try to give a solution not too different from my approach.
I know it may be something pretty simple, but I'm not very familiar with bash yet

Comment: Did you mean `$(i)` which tries to execute the value as a command and replace itself with the output, or `${i}` which just inserts the value?

Comment: That solved it. thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$(i)` to `${i}`.

`$(i)` means execute a command named "i".